# HTML5: capture audio AND video combined from web browser

Tags: html, html5-video, html5-audio, asp.net-web-api

I have seen a lot of tutos and demos showing how to capture and record audio and video with a simple web page.

Bests demos so far :

Audio : http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html
Video : http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/getusermedia/record-user-webm.html

I am looking for capturing and recording **both streams** at the same time. I am interested even if it works only on a particular browser on a particular platform.

I think it is not possible, but not sure. Has somebody found a trick to capture both audio and video **simultaneously** with a web page ?

Comment: Did you manage to get a good solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

hi trying to do the same may be you should look at

[http://jsfiddle.net/james2doyle/URyLt/]

let me know if you mange to do thanks

```
$("button").click(do_it);

function do_it() {
    var obj = {}, txt="";
    if (this.id == "video") {
        obj = {
            video: true,
            audio: true
        };
        txt = "<video>";
    } else {
        obj = {
            video: false,
            audio: true
        };
        txt = "<audio>";
    }
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(obj, function(stream) {
        $("#result").empty();
        var output = $(txt).appendTo("#result")[0],
            source = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
        output.autoplay = true;
        output.src = source;
        console.log(stream);
        window.a = stream; //debug
        $("span#name").html("Camera name: <b>" + stream.videoTracks[0].label + "</b><br>" + "Mic name: <b>" + stream.audioTracks[0].label + "</b>");
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        err.code == 1 && (alert("You can click the button again anytime to enable."))
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this experiment. It works in Chrome and FF nightly. Check out the repo: https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC

Here can you try out a live demo: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/PHP/